# What does it mean when $Y$ is the positive part of a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I don't know if this is formal terminology, or not, but I have seen it used in some articles in the past where, e.g, $X \sim N(0,1)$ or $X \sim U(-1, 1$), i.e., some distribution symmetric about $X = 0$, and then it is said that $Y$ is "the positive part of $X$."

What does this actually mean mathematically? I.e., how is $Y$ related to $X$ mathematically?
I believe it should look something like

$$
Y = \begin{cases}
X & \text{if } X > 0 \\
??? & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

What is ??? is this case?

Comment: I think ??? is zero

Comment: More generally the positive part of *any real number* is defined as $x^+=\max\{x,0\}$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Is this a formal definition?

Comment: @user5965026 of course. The maximum of any two real numbers is always formally defined. Look, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts

Comment: @NapD.Lover Would that mean $x^+$ has a mixed probability distribution, where if $x < 0$, then $x^+$ has probability 0.5 and if $x > 0$, then $x^+$ has the right half of the probability distribution of $x$? This is assuming that $x$ follows some distribution symmetrical about $x=0$.

Comment: @user5965026 indeed, you’ll have a point mass at $0$ with chance, in general, $P(X<0)$ and so on.

Comment: Better to think of $X^+$ as having the same PDF as $X$ on $(0, \infty)$ and having a probability mass of mass $0.5$ at $0$.  (... under your assumption of symmetric PDF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given random variable, $X$, the positive part is
$$  X^+ = \max\{0,X\}  $$
and the negative part is
$$  X^- = \max\{0,-X\}  \text{.}  $$
Notice that both parts are nonnegative.  This confirms the comment to the Question: "???" is $0$.

This definition exactly parallels the definition of [positive and negative parts of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts).

Comment: Is there a such thing as a random variable $Z = X | X > 0$, which reads "$Z$ is a random variable that is $X$ given that $X > 0$." Doesn't read like it makes sense to me but just wondering.

Comment: @user5965026 : This would require that $X$ is a positive variable (its PDF is $0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$) or that $Z$ is unnormalized.  You can fix the latter by normalizing it -- dividing by $\int_{(0,\infty)}$ of the PDF of $X$.

Comment: So in this situation would $Z$ be a valid random variable? What I defined as $Z$ is what I was initially going to guess what is meant by the "positive part of $X$".

Comment: @user5965026 : You posit that $X$ has a symmetric PDF, so its PDF is not $0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$.  Therefore, the total probability of your $Z$ is $1/2$.  This means your $Z$ is not a valid random variable.  If you double the PDF everywhere, normalizing it, it becomes one .